# JavaScript id output only displays for a second then dissapears

Tags: javascript

I am making a simple JavaScript function where you enter two numbers in a form and then the function determines if the sum of the two numbers is a prime. It all works but when the function displays a message with the document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML and

it is only on the web page for one second then disappears. I want to make it so the message stays until you click on the button again. I have searched this site and other site but have not been able to find anything.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/prime.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
function prime()
 {
  // get the values from the form
 var x= document.forms["frm1"]["x"].value; 
 var y= document.forms["frm1"]["y"].value;
  //test the values of the form
 if (x == "null"|| x=="" || isNaN(x)|| y=="null" || y==""|| isNaN(y)){
 alert("You must enter two numbers.");
 exit;
 }
  //change variables to number and add them together
  var number = (parseInt(x)+ parseInt(y));
   var a="";
 var prime = true;

  //check to make sure number is not less than one
 if (number <= 1){
 alert("Sorry " +number+ " is not a prime.");
 prime = false;
 exit;
 }
   //check if number is a prime
for (var dividby = 2; dividby <= number / 2; dividby++){
if(number % dividby == 0)
    prime = false;
break;

}
    //send congratulations
if(prime==true){

a="congratulations " + number + " is a prime!";
}
   //send condolences
else{
a="Sorry "+number+ " is not a prime.";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=a;

}

</script>
</head>

<body id="elem">
<div class="div"></div>
<div> 
    <br>
<h1>PRIME NUMBERS</h1>
<p>Please enter two numbers to be added and see if the result is a prime.</p><br>
<form name="frm1" >
<input type="text" name="x"> 
+ <input type="text" name="y">
<button onclick="prime()">click me</button>
</form>
<br>
<p id="demo"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form is submitting - either prevent default for the action on the button (or prevent default on submit for the form) or use an alert to prevent it from continuing on to submit the form.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your "click me" button is actually submitting the form, causing the page to reload (since your `<form>` doesn't have an `action` attribute, it submits to the same page). The `<button>` tag defaults to `type="submit"`. To make it NOT a submit button, you need to change it like this:

`<button onclick="prime()" type="button">click me</button>`

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the code, and what happens is simple: your form is posted when you click the button.

In the button onClick, write onClick=" return prime();" and add a

```
return false;
```

in your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

In your form tag, just add onsubmit="return false;" like this-

```
<form name="frm1" onsubmit="return false;" >
```

This will prevent your form from being submitted.